# Why am I able to modify a unique_ptr by a reference to .get()?

Tags: c++, reference

```
struct
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
    operator int*() { return p.get(); }
} p;
(int*&)p = (int*)0x5000;
std::cout << p.p.get();
```

Compiles and prints out 0x5000 on MSVC and g++. I'm not sure why this works (or if this is a compiler bug) considering unique_ptr::get returns by value and my operator int* returns by value as well, so I should just be modifying temporary copies if anything.

Comment: This is about as undefined as [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) gets.

Comment: C++, as a general principle, gives you the freedom to do whatever you want, even if all you're doing is shooting yourself in the foot. Documentation and following good convention are your friends.

Comment: the c-style cast is an unrestricted godhammer. If you want the square peg in the round hole, a c-style cast will make it happen. Reality kicks in as soon as you try to use the square peg as a round peg and you find it's still square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as layout go, we can speculate that your object `p` is laid out the same as an object of type `int*`.

That's because the type of `p` is a struct whose only data member is a `unique_ptr<int>`, and that in turn is effectively a struct whose only data member is an `int*`. (It probably also has an empty base class that contains the deleter.)

This is all speculation since none of this is specified by the language rules, but it's a good guess, since it's as efficient a representation as one can imagine.

Just because it's laid out the same as an int pointer does of course not *make* your object into an int pointer, but if you pretend it is one and overwrite it (which you're not allowed to do), then the above explains what you see.

Comment: Ahhh now I get it. I thought the cast was doing something with the operator int* but that's totally unrelated, I can remove that operator and it still 'works'.

Comment: @Artikash: correct; you're literally just overwriting the object representation with data of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

```
(int*&)p
```

Stop right there!

This is the undefined behavior police and what you're doing there is not legal at all. You can't just cast your struct and pretend its an `int*&` and write to it while it's clearly not, classic example of UB.

`get()` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Artikash It's not legal to the UB police, it's legal to the C++ standard, it's just UB.

Comment: @Artikash The c-style cast strips away all of the protections. It effectively tells the compiler, "This is OK. I know what I'm doing." If you are wrong, badness happens.

Comment: @Artikash • the reason why this kind of dangerous stuff is legal (albeit UB), is because C++ is founded on performance, and as a systems programming language.  It is not a nanny language.  It does not protect you from shooting yourself in the foot.  If the language added a bunch of sanity checking to disallow this kind of behavior, it would lose a lot of its optimization and performance characteristics... and then those who would otherwise use C++ would use a different language that would be more performant.  But they don't have to, they have C++.